# Stand-alone Composer package for CRUD with PHP 8

Tags: database, web-development, php, mysql

For years, I've been making do with the outdated and ill-supported [php-activerecord](https://packagist.org/packages/php-activerecord/php-activerecord) to do very simple insert and update operations for a tiny script that is for my own use and doesn't need to be a full-blown app with a front end for other users, etc.

Now that I'm using PHP 8, it appears that it's time to find something new to accomplish this **very basic** CRUD interaction with my MySQL database. A quick search of Packagist reveals that the most popular CRUD packages are all designed for Laravel, CakePHP, or similar.

Is there a PHP CRUD solution out there with a sizeable community of users that works with PHP 8 and doesn't require the use of a web application framework? I would prefer a Composer package, but would accept something else provided it's lightweight and easy to install and use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use illuminate/database package

The Illuminate Database component is a full database toolkit for PHP, providing an expressive query builder, ActiveRecord style ORM, and schema builder. It currently supports MySQL, Postgres, SQL Server, and SQLite.

- **Usage Instructions**

First, create a new "Capsule" manager instance.

***Capsule aims to make configuring the library for usage outside of the Laravel framework.***

Once the Capsule instance has been registered.
You may use it like so:

- Query Builder
- Schema Builder
- Eloquent ORM

....
[Package Repository](https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/database)